# rackmount network USB hubs?

Tags: usb, rackmount

We are virtualizing our license servers and have to start using network USB hubs for the authentication keys.  The ones I've found will be messy in a rack.  Has anyone ever seen a rackmountable version?  If that's not an option, are there any rackmountable normals hubs?  Or maybe some setup I haven't come up with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like this:

[**Metal 7-Port USB 2.0 Powered Slim Hub for PC-MAC with Power Adapter**](http://www.qualitycables.com/productdetails1.cfm?sku=USBG-7U2ML&cats=&catid=104%2C653%2C210%2C212)

[image]

> Industrial USB Hub with 7 Ports
>   feature a rugged metal enclosure.

Or this one with 12 ports:

**[Industrial 12-Port USB 2.0 Powered Hub for PC-MAC DIN-RAIL Mount](http://www.usbgear.com/computer_cable_details.cfm?sku=USBG-12U2ML&cats=104&catid=104%2C653%2C210%2C212)**

[image: Image of an Industrial 12-Port USB 2.0 Powered Hub]

> Industrial USB Hub with 12 Ports
>   feature a rugged metal enclosure.

Comment: Better, but it doesn't look rackmountable without having to mount it to a board first.

Comment: "12-port hub, you can wall-mount or install onto a DIN rail for convenient access to the ports."

Comment: Ok, now that's much closer to what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Well even at 1U having splattnes suggested devices occupy a rack space seems a bit of a waste - these devices seem easy enough to mount inside a rack cabinet but outside of the actual 19" mount-space. Mounting them to a rack shelf first if you really need them inside that space should also be easy and cheap.

Actual rack-mountable equipment is hard to come by when we're talking about smaller stuff - the options are usually limited to large-scale bays to fit a lot (=more than a couple) of specific devices, like old school modems and whatnot, or *very* expensive custom frames to hold (usually very expensive) small hardware like the simpler cisco aironet controllers.

I'd say (sadly) you're looking at finding a decent generic shelf to house these things in that satisfies your need for order - or just pin them somewhere to the walls or the rails of the rack.

Answer (score 0):

What i've discovered on gearslutz.com: http://www.gearslutz.com/board/so-much-gear-so-little-time/71862-rackmount-usb-hub-16-ports-2.html

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but thought I'd make an updated answer.
USBGear/Coolgear now has several direct rack-mount models:

[Industrial 16-Port USB 2.0 Rack Mount Hub with Built-in Power Supply](http://usbgear.com/CG-1600i-RM.html)

[Industrial 16-Port USB 3.0 Din-Rail/WallMount Hub with output up to 1.5A Charging per port](http://usbgear.com/USB3-16U1.html)

Fair disclosure: I work for the company and found this thread in our logs.